# Math-Based logic game: 6 holes in the ground, and a gopher is in one and can move adjacently, while the farmer can check any hole on the line.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, game-theory

*Suppose there are 6 holes in the ground in a line. Each day the gopher moves to an
adjacent hole to the one he's in of his choice (but he never stays put). The farmer
checks one hole per day for the gopher anywhere in the line, after he's moved. Does
she have a strategy that is guaranteed to  find him? What's the smallest number of
checks she has to make to be sure she  finds him eventually?*

I drew a line with 6 circles for the holes.

If the farmer starts at hole 1, and for example the gopher is in hole 2, then the first day the gopher will not be caught, then the second day, the gopher must move to hole 1 or 3, so the farmer can check 3. If the gopher isn't there, then the farmer knows that on the next day, the gopher must be a hole 2, and the farmer captures the gopher. This is an example, but I can't find a pattern.

Comment: In your example with three holes, the farmer only need to check hole 2 twice and is done.

Comment: Indeed you're right with 3 holes, but with 6 holes where I don't know where the gopherr starts, I still have 1/6 chance of having the gopher and farmer be at the same hole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: If on day 1 gopher was at hole $i$ and on day $n$ it was at hole $j$, what can be said about difference $i-j$?

Hint 2: If farmer checks the holes in sequence 1,2,3..., gopher can still slip away:
$$\texttt{_F__G_} \to \texttt{__FG__} \to \texttt{__GF__} \to \texttt{_G__F_}$$ But what if farmer knows 3 holes where the gopher can't be every time?

Comment: You're right the gopher moves before the farmer checks so the gopher can slip away. I don't understand how I would compute the I - j since the gopher can go back and forth from holes

Comment: You cannot compute $i-j$, but if you, for example, check how the set of possible differences changes with the number $n$, it might give you some insight.

Comment: So ie i = 3, then on day n = 3, j = {1,3,5}, but how do I interpret multiple values of j?

Comment: Parity consideration shows $i-j$ will have same parity as $n$ because if the gopher starts in an even hole: the next must be odd, and so on. Reverse for odd starts.